# How to make the graph to specific layout

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For the artistic,the graph layout could be more important sometimes.So I must to put a bad sentence to describe the clumsy `GraphLayout` of `Mathematica` but my poor vocabulary.My target is:

[image]

This is my code

```
    g = Graph[{1, 7, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 7, 7 <-> 6, 
   7 <-> 3, 6 <-> 4, 6 <-> 5, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4, 4 <-> 5}, 
  VertexSize -> Large, 
  GraphLayout -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", 
    "VertexPartition" -> {3, 4}}, 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black], 
  VertexShape -> Graphics[{Thick, Circle[]}], 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center]]
```

[image]

I know the `VertexCoordinates` can achieve me.But write so much coordinates isn't a sensible option.

If I use a `Rotate` like following,then the label is followed.

```
Rotate[g, 3 Pi/2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g2 = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> RotationTransform[3 Pi/2] @ GraphEmbedding[g]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, you can use

```
g2 = SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> (RotationMatrix[3 Pi/2].# & /@ 
         GraphEmbedding[g])]
```

> same picture

```
SetProperty[g, VertexCoordinates -> (ScalingMatrix[1/5, {1, 0}].# & /@ 
       RotationMatrix[3 Pi/2].# & /@ GraphEmbedding[g])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Ok.I have to Rotate it in the last.But this is a not bad solution.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Another qeustion that can I make 1,7,6 be more near to 2,3,4,5?

Comment: @yode, thank you for the accept. Re your second question, perhaps `VertexCoordinates -> ((RotationMatrix[3 Pi/2].# & /@   GraphEmbedding[g]) /. -1. -> -.25)`?

Comment: Thanks for your promption.Maybe there is a better solution derive from you.`SetProperty[g,VertexCoordinates->ScalingTransform[0.3,{0,1}]@*RotationTransform[3 Pi/2]@GraphEmbedding[g]]`

Comment: @yode I agree that's much better.